# Grammatical names and functions

Tags: grammaticality

What is the grammatical name and function for the sentence "if my mother had more money"

The full context is
I am certain that if my mother had more money, she would have been willing to compromise and pay for the car

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: "If" is a conditional preposition here, thus "if my mother had more money" is a preposition phrase functioning as a conditional adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ. It may be helpful, particularly for English language learners who consult prescriptive, pedagogic grammar resources, to point out that your answer follows CGEL's categorization. ESL teachers and the grammar resources they and their students consult are more likely to categorize _if_ as a conjunction and _if my mother had more money_ as a clause.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a sentence, it's a phrase. The full sentence is an example of the conditional; what this site https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/
calls a 'type 2 conditional'. *If [something was true], [something else] would happen.*